# Как установить GIT или SVN?

Tags: svn, git, сервер

Дня доброго :)Суть проблемыЕсть локальный сервер по адресу какому-то, на нем уже крутится как и положено web сервер, ssh и прочее.Нужно поставить на него сервер GIT или SVN. Без разницы что.Наверное лучше GIT.Вопрос, как установить туда сервер GIT чтобы я с локальной машины мог туда лить проекты.**//upd**Есть IP и отдельный сервак.Установил subversion сделал проект на серваке.Есть пользователь test с паролем testsubversion.conf![alt text][1]virtualhost![alt text][2]Вывод в браузере![alt text][3]Папка project в корне сайта есть! Так же сайт по порту 8080 открывается нормально, но не могу привязаться к svn.**//UPD 2**Просто везде написано сделайте так, сделайте так, в итоге нифига не работает и приходится задавать вопросы.Почему те кто выкладывают как настроить или установить SVN не дают полного описания? Возможные ошибки и прочее?!Суть проблемы, есть сервак, хочу на него установить SVN, настроить его нормально(желательно чтобы кто-то помог), пусть ссылками ну и ответами нормальными. Пару ссылок на то как вообще грамотно юзать SVN, как с проектами работать.Смысл в том что сейчас эта штука оказалась нужной, но до этого никогда её не использовал.  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uD9O8.png  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQfZs.png  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbMJA.png

Comment: Ось какая? В Ubuntu на пример apt-get install gitosis.

Comment: centos ось

Comment: ну тогда вероятно yum install git-core

Comment: Что бы не было forbidden, нужно в project положить index (php, html) или разрешть индейцу листинг каталога project. Да, и владелец project wwwdata:www (или кто там у вас)

Comment: Да хрен бы с ним с форбидден. SVN не просит ни пароля ни логина для авторизации.Что делать то?

Comment: up up up up

Answer (score 2):

Установить по [руководству](http://githowto.com/ru/).Лить по фтп :)Или как нужно?

Comment: Обновил ответ.Или виртуальный хост создавать не нужно было для этого?

Answer (score 1):

Простой ман по SVN на английском: [Subversion on CentOS](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Subversion/). На русском: [Установка subversion и WEB_DAV_SVN](http://dandreev.com/blog/administrirovanie/svoj-svn-server-ustanovka-subversion-na-centos/).

Answer (score 1):

[Вот](http://rogerdudler.github.com/git-guide/index.ru.html) еще один ман.